# searching through text file in terminal

Tags: linux, unix, awk, grep

Hi this might be a basic question for many, but it has however managed to eat a couple of hours of my time.

I have large data file as an output from running a script. The file contains around 15 columns and around 100,000 rows. I wish to search through the file and in columns 4,5,6,7 and 8 check for specific values( and strings ). I know I can cut the columns separately and view them or use forward search("/") in less command. The problem here is the second and third column will also contain the value (almost in every other line) I search for. I only need the values in columns 4,5,6,7 and 8 for result interpretation and also I need to view adjacent columns too. How can I accomplish this? I do not want to use any external languages such as R, python or perl, I am looking for solutions using command line commands.

i use the following command to view the file;

```
bzcat myfile.tsv.bz2 | column -t | less -S
```

Any inputs will be appreciated.

Example of how the data looks like; (It is biological data within specific intervals)

```
col1 strt  end Sample1 Sample2 Sample3 Sample4 Sample5 p.val1 p.val2 .   ID 

ABC  1100  1200  2        2       2       2       3      NA    0.27403   PLD4     
BCD  1200  1300  4        3       4       4       2    0.88831 0.37662 CYP46A1
CDE  1300  1400  2        1       4       2       1    0.77922 0.00519   CEBPE
DEF  1400  1500  6        4       4       4       4    0.88182 NA        BRCA
EFG  1500  1600  2        6       8       10      3    0.00779 0.01558   BRCA
```

Say I want to view the file on whole and restrict my only to search columns 4,5,6,7 and 8. 
~M

Comment: Can you give an example of lines that should and shouldn't match?

Comment: This is absolutely trivial in awk but edit your question to show a specific testable example including input and output so we get the details right. Your current example doesn't qualify as it's missing the expected output and you say you want to test for "specific values" but don't tell us which values and you say you want to test colum 8 but only show 7 columns in your sample input. Post something PRECISE/EXACT that we can test a potential solution against.

Comment: Again you say you want `to search columns 4,5,6,7 and 8` but you still won't tell us what it is you want to search FOR in that sample input file or what the expected output would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until you edit your question to provide more info, is this what you want?:

```
$ awk '$4==1 && $6==4' file
BCD  2    4  1     1    4    2
```

The above was run against your posted sample input file:

```
$ cat file
col1 srt end col4 col5 col6 col7
ABC  1    2  1     1    5    2
BCD  2    4  1     1    4    2
CDE  4    6  6     5    2    5
DEF  6    8  4     4    4    4
EFG  8   10  4     4    3    4
```

Given your comment below, is this what you want:

```
$ awk '{print $0 ($4==1 && $6==4 ? " <--- HERE I AM!" : "")}' file
col1 srt end col4 col5 col6 col7
ABC  1    2  1     1    5    2
BCD  2    4  1     1    4    2 <--- HERE I AM!
CDE  4    6  6     5    2    5
DEF  6    8  4     4    4    4
EFG  8   10  4     4    3    4
```

Comment: Thank you Ed, the above command isolates the specific row and displays it. I want the specific row to be just highlighted while the whole file is open, so that I am able to note which ID it corresponds to and so on. Similar to` / ` in less command where it searches for a pattern and and `n` shows next occurrence. Just that I want to restrict that search option to specific columns when viewing.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what "highlighted while the whole file is open" means. Are you asking for some kind of cat of the file but with font color change or bold font or indenting or something else associated with the target line? Again - edit your question to show a specific testable example including input and output so we get the details right. Don't tell us what commands in less you want to emulate since that assumes we use less (which I don't - never heard of "n" in it), just tell us what you want to do with a testable example.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I'm going to assume that `tsv` means tab-separated values.

I would use perl for this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $search_term = "some_term"; 
my @columns_to_check =  ( 4,5,6,7,8 ); 

while ( <> ) {
    my @cols = split;
    for my $colnum ( @columns_to_check ) {
       if ( $cols[$colnum] =~ m/$search_term/ ) { 
            print; 
            last; 
       }
    }
}
```

Note: `$search_term` is a regular expression match. 
Also: Perl starts arrays at zero, so your column 1 might be column 0.

Comment: Hi Sobrique thank you for the answer. I am afraid I am looking for solutions using awk, grep or less command in the terminal when I am directly viewing the file.